# How to apply content based filtering in ne04j

Tags: neo4j, cosine-similarity

I have a data in below format where 1st column represents the products node, all the following columns represent properties of the products. I want to apply content based filtering algo using cosine similarity in Neo4j. For that, I believe, I need to define the fx columns as the properties of each product node and then call these properties as a vector and then apply cosine similarity between the products. I am having trouble doing two things:
1. How to define these columns as properties in one go(as the columns could be more than 100).
2. How to call all the property values as a vector to be able to apply cosine similarity.

Product f1  f2  f3  f4  f5

P1 0    1   0   1   1

P2 1    0   1   1   0

P3 1    1   1   1   1

P4          0   0   0   1   0

Comment: check this https://neo4j.com/graphgist/a7c915c8-a3d6-43b9-8127-1836fecc6e2f

Comment: I have seen this already, but I am having trouble playing around with properties of a node. How do I take all the property values of node as a vector that can be inputted into cosine similarity formaulae.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LOAD CSS](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/load-csv/) to input your data.

For example, this query will read in your data file and output for each input line (ignoring the header line) a `name` string and a `props` collection:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///data.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ' '
WITH line SKIP 1
RETURN HEAD(line) AS name, [p IN TAIL(line) | TOFLOAT(p)] AS props
```

Even though your data has a header line, the above query skips over it, as it is not needed. In fact, we don't want to use the `WITH HEADERS` option of `LOAD CSV`, since that would convert each data line into a map, whereas it is more convenient for our current purposes to get each data line as a collection of values.

The above query assumes that all the columns are space-separated, that the first column will always contain a `name` string, and that all other columns contain the numeric values that should be put into the same collection (named `props`).

If you replace `RETURN` with `WITH`, you can append additional clauses to the query that make use of the `name` and `props` values.